# Getting error with openvpn container when using non root user

Tags: docker, openvpn

I have written this dockerfile that runs openvpn in client mode:

```
FROM  alpine:edge

RUN apk update
RUN mkdir /run/openrc
RUN touch /run/openrc/softlevel

RUN addgroup -S openvpn && adduser -S openvpn -G openvpn

RUN apk add --no-cache --update \
linux-headers

RUN apk add --no-cache bash openssl openrc
RUN apk add openvpn

RUN rc-update add openvpn default

VOLUME ["/etc/openvpn"]

RUN echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.d/ipv4.conf

CMD openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf
```

But when I run the container

```
docker run -u openvpn -v /etc/openvpn:/etc/openvpn -itd --cap-drop all  --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --device /dev/net/tun   alpine-openvpn:v1
```

I get this error when launching

```
2021-10-28 15:27:31 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
2021-10-28 15:27:31 ERROR: Cannot ioctl TUNSETIFF tun: Operation not permitted (errno=1)
2021-10-28 15:27:31 Exiting due to fatal error
```

But if I do not use openvpn user it works fine.